# Can I disable the background video effects?

Tags: rock-band-3

While playing effects/filters will occasionally be added to the video that runs in the background. While some of them are not so noticeable (b&w), others are incredibly distracting (over the top motion blur, faux-overexposure), to the point where it's difficult to concentrate on the track in the foreground.

All I want to do is lay down some beats, can I disable the background video effects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to turn off the background visual effects. The January 31st, 2011 patch increased the opacity of the note highways so that they are more visible in comparison to the background, but there's not really anything an individual user can do on their own system. There [are threads](http://www.rockband.com/forums/showthread.php?t=210324&page=1) on the Rock Band forums addressing this, but there's been no indication that this feature will be added.

If you haven't, try playing the *Beatles* edition. I ended up failing a song once because I got so distracted by the incredibly weird visuals that I stopped playing. RB3's visuals are at least tamer in comparison. ;)

Comment: oh. It actually makes some sense with the Beatles though, it's an authentic experience. :)